# Why are there two inputs being sent to database as opposed to one?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I just don't understand how this is happening.  Upon the user entering text, two copies of it get sent to the database instead of one.  I'm pretty sure my code is correct but just so uncertain as to why it's sending duplicate copies of user input in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here's my `create_posts_table` in the migrations folder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('body', 140);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

posting to db:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request, Post $post) {
        // create post
        $createdPost = $request->user()->posts()->create([
            'body' => $request->body
        ]);

        // return response
        return response()->json($post->with('user')->find($createdPost->id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the `store` method too. or how you're inserting the data to mysql

Comment: @SaadSuri which store method are you referring to?

Comment: @mrtest when you are inserting to your table, post that code too.

Comment: @SaadSuri posted

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu posted

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not going too much into your code, but you can just

```
$post = App\Post::firstOrCreate(['body' => 'body' => $request->body]);
```

You can try various [create](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods) or [insert](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts) methods described in documentation.

Also I do not think retrieving all posts of a user for every insert is good practice, that you are doing by using `$request->user()->posts()`.